# How to run python scripts in your laptop using configuration of another laptop

Tags: python, server, connection

I have python scripts which take huge amount of time to run so I decided to work on highest configuration pc  but the code i should run on my laptop using pc (highest configuration) because it contains user_id (in python code connection to snowflake and match all the records using user_id)
how do i go ahead??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to it would be to make a docker container and deploy the image on the endpoint as the docker container will never change configuration, wherever you deploy it.